# Join one field of one table to many fields of other table

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join a primary key of one table to many foreign keys of other table.
I want to join codigo_arbitro from table equipo_arbitral to anotador, crono and op24 from table partido.
If I join the anotador field only it's no problem but when I try to join another field Mysql throws the error not unique table alias p.
It's the code I tryed.

```
SELECT Codigo_arbitro, Hora, PABELLON.Codigo_localidad AS 'Loca' FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P.Anotador
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P.Crono
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P.Op24
```

It's the structure of the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPO_ARBITRAL(Codigo_arbitro INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Licencia     VARCHAR(4), Nombre VARCHAR(20), Apellidos VARCHAR(20), 
Email VARCHAR(20), Telefono1 INT(9), Telefono2 INT(9), Cuenta INT(20), 
Cod_localidad INT(3), PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_arbitro));

CREATE TABLE PARTIDO(Codigo_Partido INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, EquipoA INT NOT NULL, EquipoB INT NOT NULL, Fecha DATE,
Hora TIME, Codigo_pabellon INT NOT NULL, Codigo_categoria INT NOT NULL, Tipo VARCHAR(10), Jornada INT NOT NULL, ArbPrin INT,  ArbAux INT, Anotador INT, Crono INT, Op24 INT,
FOREIGN KEY (EquipoA) REFERENCES EQUIPO (Codigo_equipo), FOREIGN KEY (EquipoB) REFERENCES EQUIPO (Codigo_equipo), FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_categoria) REFERENCES CATEGORIA (Codigo_Categoria),
FOREIGN KEY (ArbPrin) REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (Codigo_arbitro), FOREIGN KEY (ArbAux) REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL(Codigo_arbitro),
FOREIGN KEY (Anotador) REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (Codigo_arbitro), FOREIGN KEY (Crono) REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (Codigo_arbitro), FOREIGN KEY (Op24) REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (Codigo_arbitro),
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_pabellon) REFERENCES PABELLON (Codigo_pabellon));
```

There are the data of the table partidos.

```
 Hora,     ArbPrin, ArbAux, Anotador, Crono, Op24
'17:30:00',  '5',    '81',    '86',   '78', '87',
```

Result will be like this:

```
Codigo_arbitro   Hora
       5         17:30
      81         17:30
      86         17:30
      78         17:30
      87         17:30
```

Comment: paste your table details

Comment: I delete the other post. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Every joined table should have a separate alias, even if it's the same table.
Also, from the description of your problem, you need a UNION of 3 separate JOIN queries.

```
SELECT Codigo_arbitro, Hora, PABELLON.Codigo_localidad AS 'Loca' FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P1 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P1.Anotador
        UNION
SELECT Codigo_arbitro, Hora, PABELLON.Codigo_localidad AS 'Loca' FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P2 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P2.Crono
        UNION
SELECT Codigo_arbitro, Hora, PABELLON.Codigo_localidad AS 'Loca' FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
        INNER JOIN PARTIDO P3 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P3.Op24;
```

Comment: your `does not work` because you should not mention **`table alias name`** in the before the column name, you should must change you query, for example: **`table1.coulumnname`**

Comment: I don't get it. Your answer looks exactly like mine.

Answer (score -1):

you should menion `alias` table like as :

> P1, P2, P3

you should change and mention the alias name:

```
  SELECT 
  Codigo_arbitro,                         --- alias table name 
  Hora,                                   --- alias table name
  PABELLON.Codigo_localidad AS 'Loca' 
  FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
  INNER JOIN PARTIDO P1 
  ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P1.Anotador
  INNER JOIN PARTIDO P2 
  ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P2.Crono
  INNER JOIN PARTIDO P3 
  ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P3.Op24
```

Comment: I try it but it don't work. Now I haven't any error but the query don't show anything. It will show 3 results, the 3 I have insert on my table.

Comment: if you can paste table details

Comment: did you know the hows result looks like, if you know paste the result

Comment: Ah. apparently you don't need JOIN all these tables, you need a union of JOINs.

Comment: @Ashalynd, because he not post the all detail, just post little bit details only, so just I'm alter his query

Comment: (-1) I want the reason for down vote, if you cant give the details I'll tell `stackoverflow team`

Comment: well, the reason was that your answer looked exactly like the first version of mine, and then you said that my answer wasn't right. the combination of these two factors looked a bit strange.

Comment: @Ashalynd, now also I said your `old query` is `wrong one`. so, you have **`another one id`**, but your not **`add with your current id`**, this too bad. And you should must **`add with your current id`** or otherwise **`remove that`**,..

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you mean. also, your current answer is in any case incorrect, because the question author seems to need a union of 3 join queries.